# Is "be brought up sharp by..." a very tricky expression?

Tags: phrases

I found this sentence very tricky. It's under the entry of "sharp" in a dictionary:

> he was brought up sharp by Helen's voice

The related definition of "sharp" is:

> in a sudden or abrupt way

What is this sentence talking about? I at first decipher it as "He suddenly grew up in Helen's voice", which I myself found very weird. Then I consult the dictionary and find "bring sb.up" can mean "to rebuke sb“. I am still confused and not very sure about the meaning. Help me.

Comment: You're on the right track with how "bring somebody up" can mean "to rebuke someone".

Comment: @J.R.: I think "brought up" here is a metaphoric reference to the fact that he was "deep in thought" before being brought up to the level of interaction with his actual surroundings. There's no particular implication of "rebuke", and no suggestion that Helen's voice is sharp, or that she's delivering a sharp rebuke. As OP already sees, "sharp" here just refers to how *quickly* he rose to full awareness.

Comment: @dennylv: We'd need the preceding context to give a definitive answer as to what "brought up" means here. I'm guessing since it's being done by just a voice, it probably means "interrupted from his private reveries". But if he was specifically doing something in the preceding sentence, it would probably make more sense to see it as meaning "**stopped** from doing [whatever it was]".

Comment: ... OED **bring up** 7. intr. *To come to anchor; hence, to come to a stand, **to stop**, ‘pull up’.*

Comment: Yes, This definitely means that whatever he was doing prior to Helen speaking was *interrupted and stopped* **abruptly** (*brought up* **sharp**) at the sound of Helen's voice.  And I think @Fumble's interpretation of brought up to a level of consciousness is a pretty apt description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To [**bring** [somebody] **up** [sharp, short, etc.]](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bring+up+short) only has indirect implications of "rebuke". In OP's context the core meaning is **stop**, deriving from nautical usage...

> OED ***bring up*** (intransitive verb): *To come to anchor; hence, to come to a stand, to stop, ‘pull up’.*

It just so happens that "rebuking" (scolding, telling off) is a common way you might cause someone to stop doing something, hence the association in the minds of native speakers.

It's also worth noting that where the particular activity being stopped isn't explicitly specified, it's often a *literal* reference (to physical motion). But common *figurative* usages involve stopping a "train of thought", "line of argument", etc. (in which context one can also see *being brought **up*** as contrasting with *being **deep** in thought*).

I'd also point out that ***sharp*** (correctly defined by OP as *in a sudden or abrupt way* here) may often occur as ***sharply*** (similar to *safe/safely, quick/quickly* as covered by [an earlier question on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8328/which-is-correct-drive-safe-or-drive-safely)). That's to say, it functions adverbially regardless of whether the explicit adverbial suffix ***-ly*** is present or not.

Finally, I'll just say that, [as this NGram shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28brought%20up%20sharp%29%2b%28brought%20up%20sharply%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,%28brought%20up%20sharp%29%20%2b%20%28brought%20up%20sharply%29;,c0), OP's usage has declined considerably from its peak a century ago. I wouldn't go so far as to say it's "dated", but it's certainly headed in that direction.

Comment: Then I would try to paraphrase this sentence in different ways as "He was deterred/startled suddenly by Helen's voice.", or "Helen's voice awakened him from his meditation/delibreation/pondering". Which version would sound proper？

Comment: @dennylv: Per my first comment, we don't *know* what the preceding context is, so it's meaningless to speculate on whether he was *startled/awakened* from some (internal) thought process/dream, or *stopped/deterred* from some (external, physical) action. The "proper" version would be the one that fitted the context - but obviously it's just a dictionary entry, so there is no context. I wouldn't worry about it though - this use of *bought up* isn't common, but it's one of relatively few things that can happen to you *sharp*. That's why they picked it for the example.